# Driving direction is not showing in Google Map While all points are getting after fetching them?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using this code to draw driving direction between two points. My map is loading well and the points are getting while parsing.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.esysolutions.dilosys.Map.DirectionsJSONParser;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

public class LocationDrivingMap extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap map;
    ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.locationdrivingdirection);

        markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        map = fm.getMap();

        if (map != null) {

            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            String url = getDirectionsUrl();

            Log.d("............FULL URL...................", url);

            DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

            downloadTask.execute(url);

        }
    }

    private String getDirectionsUrl() {

        String parameters = "origin=13.687140112679154,100.535258688032630&destination=13.683660045847258,100.53900808095932&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";

        String output = "json";

        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"
                + output + "?" + parameters;

        return url;

    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            Log.d(">>>>>>>Inside DownloadTask<<<<<<<<<", url[0]);

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try {
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);

        }
    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(
                String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);

                Log.d("++++++++++++++++++++Route", "" + routes);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;

            // Traversing through all the routes
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);

                    Log.d("???????????????  Points", "" + points);

                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);

                Log.d("*************************  LineOptions", ""
                        + lineOptions);
                lineOptions.width(2);
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED);

            }

            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(
                    13.687140112679154, 100.535258688032630), 2.0f));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Log inside point gets this value, but path is not showing here.

> [lat/lng: (13.68719,100.53523), lat/lng: (13.68723,100.53524), lat/lng: (13.68728,100.53526), lat/lng: (13.68728,100.53526), lat/lng: (13.68721,100.5355), lat/lng: (13.68715,100.53573), lat/lng: (13.68709,100.53591), lat/lng: (13.68699,100.53616), lat/lng: (13.68693,100.53629), lat/lng: (13.68689,100.53635), lat/lng: (13.68679,100.5365), lat/lng: (13.68666,100.53666), lat/lng: (13.68656,100.53679), lat/lng: (13.68643,100.53691), lat/lng: (13.68622,100.53707), lat/lng: (13.68554,100.5375), lat/lng: (13.68509,100.5378), lat/lng: (13.68478,100.53804), lat/lng: (13.68469,100.53812), lat/lng: (13.68461,100.53818), lat/lng: (13.68456,100.53823), lat/lng: (13.68449,100.53828), lat/lng: (13.68439,100.53837), lat/lng: (13.68406,100.53868), lat/lng: (13.68381,100.53894), lat/lng: (13.68371,100.53905)]

Comment: I don't think the question is clear, and the presented solution does not describe how it solves whatever the problem was. Accordingly, I recommend this is closed as "Unclear".

Answer (score 0):

Here I got the Solution for this Question :

```
package com.esysolutions.dilosys.v2;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

import com.esysolutions.dilosys.Map.DirectionsJSONParser;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

public class LocationDrivingMap extends FragmentActivity {

    GoogleMap map;
    ArrayList<LatLng> markerPoints;
    MarkerOptions op;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.locationdrivingdirection);

        markerPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

        SupportMapFragment fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        map = fm.getMap();

        LatLng point1 = new LatLng(13.687140112679154, 100.535258688032630);
        LatLng point2 = new LatLng(14.683660045847258, 105.53900808095932);

        markerPoints.add(point1);
        markerPoints.add(point2);

        if (map != null) {

            map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

            for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {

                op = new MarkerOptions();
                op.position(markerPoints.get(j));

                if (markerPoints.size() == 1) {
                    op.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
                } else if (markerPoints.size() == 2) {
                    op.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_RED));

                }
                map.addMarker(op);
            }

            if (markerPoints.size() >= 2) {
                LatLng origin = markerPoints.get(0);
                LatLng dest = markerPoints.get(1);

                // Getting URL to the Google Directions API
                String url = getDirectionsUrl(origin, dest);

                DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();


                downloadTask.execute(url);
            }

        }

    }

    private String getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + ","
                + origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;

        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/"
                + output + "?" + parameters;

        return url;
    }

    /** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(strUrl);

            // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Connecting to url
            urlConnection.connect();

            // Reading data from url
            iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    iStream));

            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

            String line = "";
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        } finally {
            iStream.close();
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Fetches data from url passed
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try {
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);

        }
    }

    /** A class to parse the Google Places in JSON format */
    private class ParserTask extends
            AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<List<HashMap<String, String>>>> {

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> doInBackground(
                String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> routes = null;

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DirectionsJSONParser parser = new DirectionsJSONParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<List<HashMap<String, String>>> result) {
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions lineOptions = null;
            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();

            // Traversing through all the routes
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                lineOptions = new PolylineOptions();

                // Fetching i-th route
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = result.get(i);

                // Fetching all the points in i-th route
                for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }

                // Adding all the points in the route to LineOptions
                lineOptions.addAll(points);
                lineOptions.width(2);
                lineOptions.color(Color.RED);

            }

            // Drawing polyline in the Google Map for the i-th route
            map.addPolyline(lineOptions);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```